# Failing to install 'lmbd' package for Stable diffusion web-ui

Tags: artificial-intelligence, apple-m1, lmdb, stable-diffusion

I am trying to install the Stable Diffusion Web-UI via terminal on a Mac M1 by followings this [official GitHub guide](https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui/wiki/Installation-on-Apple-Silicon#downloading-stable-diffusion-models). However, when I attempt to start the webui.sh module, I encounter the following error:

```
 note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> lmdb

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.

[notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.0 -> 23.0.1
[notice] To update, run: python3.10 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

I have tried several methods to solve this issue, but I have been unsuccessful. I have upgraded pip to the latest version as suggested, but nothing seems to be working. Does anyone have any ideas on how to make it work?

I've tried to start the stable diffusion web-ui but i'm stuck with this error

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. Steps I did

1. updated the Macos to latest version
2. Run `xcode-select --install` wait to install
3. cd stable-diffusion-webui
4. ./webui.sh